# Redirecting all htm files to cfm with tomcat

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion, url-rewriting

We have a ton of HTML pages that are just copies of their CFM counterparts. This seems highly inefficient and I'd like to know if there was a way to simply redirect all requests for .htm files to the .cfm file.

Another requirement is that the query string gets redirected as well

So reallyStupidDesignDecision.htm?this=true would redirect to reallyStupidDesignDecision.cfm?this=true

Comment: If you must do it with Tomcat, look into [Tuckey URL Rewrite Filter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). If you've got Apache in front, [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) would probably be a better option.

Comment: So you've got .htm files with ColdFusion code in them that doesn't get processed by the CF server?

Comment: There are a number of issues in play. I'm assuming this is CF10? Adobe customized tomcat to behave like JRun with handling rewrite and the CGI scope. So, just let us know your setup. It's very doable.

Comment: Wouldn't this be more appropriate at [sf]?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is with REST. With REST, all of your URLs have no extensions.  In your example, your URL would be something like reallyStupidDesignDecision/this=true, (there are other ways of handling parameters).

Know now that this solution would entail way more work than a filter but going forward, your pages would always have the same URL no matter what back-end language you have, plus there is a security bonus in not revealing the back-end language that is being used.